# Failing to call setDoc in firebase firestore datastore with error Unsupported field value: a custom w object

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have a set of javascript classes

```
import { Finance } from "./finance.modal";
export class User {
   private _uid: string;
   private _email: string;
   private _onboarded: boolean
   private _finance:Finance

constructor(){
      this._finance = new Finance()
   }

   public get uid():string{
    return this._uid
   }

   public set uid(val:string){
    this._uid = val
   }

   public get email():string{
    return this._email
   }

   public set email(val:string){
    this._email = val
   }

   public get onboarded():boolean{
      return this._onboarded
   }

   public set onboarded(val:boolean){
      this._onboarded = val
   }

   public get finance():Finance{
      return this._finance
   }

   public set finance(val:Finance){
      this._finance = val
   }
}
```

Finance.ts

```
export class Finance {
   private _annualIncome: []

   constructor(){
      this._annualIncome = []
   }

   public get annualIncome(){
    return this._annualIncome
   }

   public set annualIncome(val: any){
    this._annualIncome = val
   }
}
```

At a certain point i am doing a print of user which shows as below

> {"_finance":{"_annualIncome":[]},"_email":"xxx@xx.com","_uid":"b3Tu8Racoee5Al7YWdV3rWD6ihl1"}

Now, I am trying to do a setDoc as below with above data

```
async updateUser(uid: string, payload: any) {
  const userDocRef = doc(this.firestore, 'users/' + uid );
  return setDoc(userDocRef, Object.assign({},payload), { merge: true });
}
```

But this throws below error:

> [error] - ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function setDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom w object (found in field _finance in document users/b3Tu8Racoee5Al7YWdV3rWD6ihl1)

Comment: Is there really any benefit in modelling your data like this? When you use `Object.assign()`, it will only look at your classes' enumerable properties. In this case, the pseudo-private fields (they're not really [private](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)). Why not just use plain objects?

Comment: @Phil well there is. keeping objects properties private like this helps in strict code checking in typescript and saves sometime hard to debug errors.

Comment: But all your private properties are completely read/write via getters / setters 

Comment: Use a [`FirestoreDataConverter`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.firestoredataconverter#example) to wrap and unwrap the data you want to persist to Cloud Firestore.

Comment: @samthecodingman struggling to understand how to actully use it